# PACF on Smooth Time Series

Tags: regression, time-series, statsmodels, acf-pacf

I have generated a heatmap of sorts from events occurring on certain dates. This heatmap is made as a Gaussian mixture with a fixed standard deviation of 50 days for each event. The heatmap looks like this:
[image]

There seems to be some 'clumping' going on so I wanted to check the pacf plot to confirm my suspicion. I am expecting to see a partial autocorrelation of one and almost one at lags 0 and 1 and then negative lags after this (correct me if I have misunderstood this) and what I get is this:

[image]

This confirms my hypothesis which is nice but what is bugging me here is the extremely smooth behaviour of the partial autocorrelations. Is this to be expected for a 'smooth' function like mine, or is something awry?

The reason I am worried is that I seem to get some very weird behaviour depending on which method I use, see [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_pacf.html). For OLS for instance:

[image]

Comment: Is this daily data in the pacf computation? If the smoothing filter has a large effect, then pacf will pick up mainly properties of the smoothing filter and less of the underlying time series. My guess is that the `ols` pacf has a problem with very high multicollinearity.

Comment: Also, the series is not stationary, there is at least one mean shift. This will affect acf and pacf which assume stationary data.

Comment: What you could try is compute pacf starting from spring or summer of 2014. The second part has more events and might be less affected by the smoothing. There are few events before 2014 and daily data will be mostly driven by the filter.

Comment: @Josef Very good suggestions. I'd say you're right in that the filter really screws with my timeseries here. Do you have any suggestions on how to make an intensity map from discrete events like this? My two initial thoughts are the one described above and a weekly count.

Comment: statsmodels does not have any time series analysis for count data yet. I would look at weekly counts. Starting from 2014, there might be enough counts per week, so that standard time series analysis gives usable results. The early time period might have too many zero and small counts to ignore the count features and discreteness of the data.

Comment: Another possiblility for weekly count data. Use poisson regression with lagged counts, or something like moving average of past counts, as regressors. (That could be used for something like the Poisson equivalent of OLS-pacf.) (But I don't have any experience with this.)

Comment: Aside: I think the smoothed intensity plot looks good and informative. It's just not the best for further analysis like pacf and other time series features, or for prediction.